# Pass Parameter to Mysql Stored Procedure and get response using Node Js

Tags: mysql, node.js, stored-procedures

i have one parameter suppose 'x' . I want to pass it in a stored procedure of mysql using node js and that sp will return a response to me !
How will i pass the parameter to call a particular sp !!

```
function send(user){

connection.query('CALL SPNAME(?)',[user],function (err, rows, fields) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        console.log(rows);
    });
    connection.end();
}
```

//user is my parameter

Comment: What driver are you using to connect to MySQL?. Your code throws an error?.

Comment: Mysql module pf npm